# Excel - how to split a list in a cell into separate cells

Tags: excel

I am trying to split these names up so that are in a cell each. I have tried text to columns and that doesn't do the job.

[image]

Comment: What version of Excel are you using?

Answer (score 0):

you can use the code below to split the string by chr(10), which presents a line feed character. Please note the assumption behind input data header and output column. Please also note that dictionary works in this case only because dictionaries in VBA somehow maintains ordering - this is unlikely to be the case in other programming languages.

```
Public Sub sub_test()

    Dim wsThis As Worksheet: Set wsThis = ActiveSheet
    Dim vData As Variant
    Dim dicOutput As Object: Set dicOutput = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    Dim vTemp As Variant
    Dim vLine As Variant
    Dim i As Long


    With wsThis
        ' Read data into memory - assume no header
        vData = .Range(.Range("A1"), .Range("A1").End(xlDown))

        ' Loop through each row
        For i = LBound(vData, 1) To UBound(vData, 1)
            ' Split by new line
            vTemp = Split(vData(i, 1), Chr(10))
            For Each vLine In vTemp
                ' Check if new line is empty string
                If Trim(vLine) <> vbNullString Then
                    dicOutput(vLine) = 1
                End If
            Next vLine
        Next i
        vTemp = Application.Transpose(dicOutput.keys)

        ' Output into worksheet - assume column C
        .Range("C1").Resize(UBound(vTemp, 1) - LBound(vTemp, 1) + 1, UBound(vTemp, 2) - LBound(vTemp, 2) + 1) = vTemp
    End With



End Sub
```